# Error in reading SAS files

Tags: sas

I am just playing around with SAS, writing the following code

```
options nocenter nonumber;

data vag;
infile "C:\Users\Deborah\Desktop\School\STA 318\book\veggies.txt";
input Name $ Code $ Days Number Price;
CostPerSeed = Price / Number;
run;
```

The location of the file is correct, but the error I am getting 
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /opt/sasinside/SASConfig/Lev1/SASApp/C:\Users\Deborah\Desktop\School\STA 318\book\veggies.txt.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you on EG? Or using SAS UE? Either way it looks like SAS can't see your desktop. The way around that depends on what version your on.

Answer (score 4):

You are working on Unix server, not you local PC. While you are running a local client on your PC (like SAS EG), you can't actually access local resources on your local PC because these resources needs to be made available to Unix box itself.

You have four options: 
1. Use an import Wizard in SAS EG. It will generate a data step and will use hidden SAS EG methods to convert your text file and move it as a data set to Unix server where you then can create variables that you want. 
[image]

2. See if your file system is available to you in SAS EG. Expand your workspace server. You should see "files". Expand to the folder that you are allowed to use and drag&drop your text file into there. 
   [image]
3. Upload files to the unix server using whatever file transfer method is available. Usually you would have some sort of FTP server running.
4. Also, as Joe suggested, you can install this custom task http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/06/copy-files-in-sas-eg/ 
   It can do a lot better job that step 2 or 3 because it can be part of your process, resolve macro variables and fix file formatting issues between Windows and Unix. Thanks Joe!!

Comment: Isn't there also the Copy Files EG task that Chris H created and eventually made its way into main EG?

Comment: ie: http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/06/copy-files-in-sas-eg/ (which at the time was a custom task but as of 6.1 is in EG under Tasks->Data, "Upload files to Server" etc.)

Comment: Thank @Joe! I didn't know about this step. I have just installed and it is very good! I am going to be using it all the time now! I have edited my post to incorporate your comment.